# Laravel Session Hijacking issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, session-cookies, session-hijacking

We have a web application running on Laravel 5.4. We have given this Website to an auditing service to check the vulnerabilities. Their report says that There is threat of `Session Hijacking`. In the report, They have mentioned below threat.

THREAT: Suppose there are Two users `A` and `B`

1. Log into the account of `A` and copy the `session id` and `XSRF-TOKEN` cookies of the user.
2. Now open another browser chrome, Login to the account of `B`.
3. Now paste the Cookies of `A` (`session id` and `XSRF-TOKEN` ) in place of cookies of `B` (`session id` and `XSRF-TOKEN` ).
4. Now just reload the chrome. That's it. Immediately, user `A` account will be opened.

I have tried it and they are correct. But, how to fix the issue? They recommended me to Turn on `HttpOnly` and `Secure` cookies with SSL encrypted, which I did.

Even after doing that, the issue is still there. Am I checking in the correct way? How to check the session hijacking vulnerability after setting `HttpOnly` and `Secure`?

Comment: Use HTTPS. Laravel should already have `HttpOnly` set. With those two things in place, this attack would require direct physical access to the victim's browser, at which point you've already got bigger problems.

Comment: @ceejayoz Yeah, HTTPS is already there with `HttpOnly` and `Secure`. `this attack would require direct physical access to the victim's browser` which means doing 1 to 4(mentioned in the question) to test the vulnerability is not correct right?

Comment: Automated tests will often do this - throw false positives, or be overly aggressive in what they consider a vulnerability. You can typically flag it as mitigated, and enter the steps you took. Consider adding HSTS headers, but otherwise you've done what you can.